# Search Display template for anonymous User

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-on-prem, display-template

I have a requirement where i need to show search results for anonymous users. Expected results are showing in search but it is showing default display template instead of configured respective display template. Where as when i am logged in with user to the same search page, it is showing correct display template.

Comment: Have you published the display template?

Comment: Yes, templates are working for all authenticated users, its not working only for anonymous access.